# Optimizing variadic template pack subsequence matching algorithm

Tags: c++, search, template-meta-programming, c++14, variadic

I'm building a small [MPL module in one of my utility libraries](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/tree/master/include/SSVUtils/Core/MPL) for fun and learning experience.

One of the problems I'm trying to solve is getting a list of all indices where a sequence of types appears inside another sequence of types.

Example:

```
static_assert(is_same
<
    List<int, char, int, int, char, int, double, int, char>
        ::IdxsOfSeq<int, char>,
    ListInt<0, 3, 7>
>());
```

The above code is valid and works as intended. However, finding out the indices of a subsequence in a long type sequence becomes very slow very fast.

Searching in a list with 20 or 30 elements can take up to 30 seconds of compilation time.

That would rarely be useful, but I'm also experimenting with *compile-time strings* implemented as character lists.

The current implementation of `IdxsOfSeq` basically uses `std::index_sequence` to perform a naive string matching algorithm over the type sequence.

The naive algorithm requires no preprocessing time, but the execution of the type matching requires a lot of computation time.

This is my current implementation of the string matching algorithm.

```
// Matches<bool, int> returns a ListInt<TStart> is the boolean
// is true, otherwise an empty ListInt<>
template<bool TAllTrue, int TStart> 
struct Matches;

template<int TStart> 
struct Matches<true, TStart> 
{ 
    using Type = ListInt<TStart>; 
};

template<int TStart> 
struct Matches<false, TStart>  
{ 
    using Type = ListInt<>; 
};



// GetMatch<TS, TM, TStart, TMIdxs>::Type checks if every type
// of TS (the source type sequence) starting from the index TStart
// matches every type in TM (the subsequence to find)
template<typename TS, typename TM, int TStart, typename TMIdxs> 
struct GetMatch;

template<typename TS, typename TM, int TStart, SizeT... TMIdxs> 
struct GetMatch<TS, TM, TStart, IdxSeq<TMIdxs...>>
{
    using Type = typename Matches
    <
        // True if all the types inside AreAllTrue are std::true_type
        AreAllTrue
        <
            // Type checking with index sequence expansion
            std::is_same_t
            <
                typename TS::template At<TStart + TMIdxs>,
                typename TM::template At<TMIdxs>
            >...
        >{}(),
        TStart
    >::Type;
};



// Main helper template
// Finds every occurrence of the list TM inside TS and returns its index
template<typename TS, typename TM, typename TSIdxs, typename TMIdxs>
struct IdxsOfSeqHlpr;

template<typename TS, typename TM, SizeT... TSIdxs, typename TMIdxs> 
struct IdxsOfSeqHlpr<TS, TM, IdxSeq<TSIdxs...>, TMIdxs>
{
    // ConcatLists (obviously) concatenates the contents of the
    // lists passed as template parameters in a single list
    using Type = typename ConcatLists
    <
        ListInt<>, 
        typename GetMatch<TS, TM, TSIdxs, TMIdxs>::Type...
    >::Type;
};

// If the subsequence to match is empty, return an empty ListInt<>
template<typename TS, SizeT... TSIdxs, typename TMIdxs> 
struct IdxsOfSeqHlpr<TS, List<>, IdxSeq<TSIdxs...>, TMIdxs>
{
    using Type = ListInt<>;
};



// Main typedef
// 
template<typename TS, typename TM> 
using IdxsOfSeq = typename IdxsOfSeqHlpr
<
    // Source list
    TS, 

    // Subsequence to match
    TM, 

    // Index sequence of the source list
    // Starts from 0, ends at (source_list_size - matching_list_size + 1)
    std::make_index_sequence
    <
        getClampedMin(int(TS::size - TM::size + 1), 0)
    >, 

    // Index sequence of the subsequence to match
    std::make_index_sequence<TM::size>
>::Type;
```

**Is there any part of the algorithm that can easily be optimized?**

Or is it better to rewrite the solution from scratch, using another algorithm?

Comment: Could you post a complete, compilable source file? [I managed to get your code compiling, but the static-assert doesn't pass.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4xgayaGsn21cDB8s) Notice that a *lot* of your entities are just renamed versions of standard (C++14) entities, such as `std::index_sequence` (your `IdxSeq`) and even `size_t` (your `SizeT`). It would help me to understand the code if you would just use the standard entities directly, without renaming them.

Comment: [Here's a Wandbox link to a working version,](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P2CwXApjdTIShtaF) which I wrote from scratch without particularly consulting the details of your version. I don't know any good way to "benchmark" the different versions with all kinds of big inputs, though; we need Louis Dionne in here! :)

Comment: [Here's an alternative approach,](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KWcXxmurwV94j1Ha) almost certainly worse: we could encode the list of all possible substrings into the representation of the list, so that the sentence `X is a substring of Y` translates into simply `X is a member of Y::substrings`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to throw out a fairly complicated solution here by breaking the problem into lots of smaller parts. The end result is that the compilation of the following:

```
using T = typelist<int, char, int, int, char, int, double, int, char,
                   int, char, int, int, char, int, double, int, char,
                   int, char, int, int, char, int, double, int, char,
                   int, char, int, int, char, int, double, int, char>;

static_assert(std::is_same<
    matches<T, typelist<int, char>>,
    intlist<0, 3, 7, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21, 25, 27, 30, 34>
    >::value, "!");
```

is still almost instantaneous.

The algorithm is actually going to come from an idea in Python's itertools. What we want to do is walk our typelist N at a time (where N is the match length), and just use `std::is_same` to compare. That is, taking the original problem's list:

```
using SRC = typelist<int, char, int, int, char, int, double, int, char>;
```

we want to turn it into something that looks like:

```
using X = typelist<typelist<int, char>,
                   typelist<char, int>,
                   typelist<int, int>,
                   ...
                   >;
```

And then pass that into a metafunction taking an appropriate `typelist<Ts...>` and `std::index_sequence<Is...>` do:

```
using type = concat<
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T, SUB>::value,
        typelist<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Idx>>,
        typelist<>
        >...>;
```

That's the basic idea anyway. Plus, the smaller pieces are probably going to be useful in other contexts.

---

**The Small Algorithms**

These are very straightforward and I will omit them here for brevity: `head`, `tail`, `size`, `concat` (variadic!), `any_of`, and `is_empty`.

**`take_by`**

To generate the `X` typelist above, we need something like:

```
template <typename TL, int I>
using take_by = ???
```

The implementation of this is to make a typelist that is `I` copies of `TL`, each one dropping a steadily larger prefix off the top. Once we have that, we need to zip all the iterators together. So really, I need to start with the smaller pieces...

**`skip_n`**

Given a typelist, basically just call `tail` `n` times:

```
template <typename TL, int I>
struct skip_n_impl : skip_n_impl<tail<TL>, I-1> { };

template <typename TL>
struct skip_n_impl<TL, 0> {
    using type = TL;
};

template <typename TL, int I>
using skip_n = typename skip_n_impl<TL, I>::type;
```

There may be a better way to do this, but I'm not sure. So, `skip_n<typelist<int, char, double>, 2>` is `typelist<double>`.

**`zip`**

This is the tricky part. Basically, we have a list of lists of types. If any of those typelists is empty, we're done. Otherwise, we concat all the heads with a recursive call against all the tails. We can't use `std::conditional_t` here due to eager evaluation of both parts, so I'm introducing two different `impl` types:

```
template <typename TL>
struct zip_impl;

template <typename TL, bool done>
struct zip_impl2;

template <typename TL>
struct zip_impl2<TL, true> {
    using type = typelist<>;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct zip_impl2<typelist<Ts...>, false> {
    using type = concat<typelist<typelist<head<Ts>...>>,
                        typename zip_impl<typelist<tail<Ts>...>>::type
                        >;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct zip_impl<typelist<Ts...>>
    : zip_impl2<typelist<Ts...>, any_of<is_empty<Ts>::value...>::value>
{ };

template <typename T>
using zip = typename zip_impl<T>::type;
```

This gives us the pieces to get back to `take_by`:

```
template <typename TL, int I, typename = std::make_index_sequence<I>>
struct take_by_impl;

template <typename TL, int I, std::size_t... Idx>
struct take_by_impl<TL, I, std::index_sequence<Idx...>>
{
    using iters = typelist<skip_n<TL, Idx>...>;
    using type = zip<iters>;
};

template <typename TL, int I>
using take_by = typename take_by_impl<TL, I>::type;
```

Hopefully that makes sense. First, we built up our "iterators" - which are all offset by one from each other. Then we just zip them up. Now we have the `X`, and all we need is:

`**matches**`:

```
template <typename SRC, typename SUB>
struct matches_impl
{
    template <typename TL, typename = std::make_index_sequence<size<TL>::value>>
    struct impl;

    template <typename... T, std::size_t... Idx>
    struct impl<typelist<T...>, std::index_sequence<Idx...>>
    {
        using type = concat<
            std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T, SUB>::value,
                typelist<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Idx>>,
                typelist<>
                >...>;
    };

    using type = typename impl<take_by<SRC, size<SUB>::value>>::type;
};

template <typename SRC, typename SUB>
using matches = typename matches_impl<SRC, SUB>::type;
```

Basically, we end up creating a meta-list internally that would look like:

```
intlist<0>,
typelist<>,
typelist<>,
intlist<3>,
typelist<>,
...
```

But `concat` will drop the empties, so when that gets combined, we get what we wanted - `intlist<0, 3, 7>`.